# django-registration and sha1 as hash algorithm

Tags: python, sha1, django-registration

I have been using [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration) for my django applications(thanks to `James Bennett`).I read some articles which spoke about the importance of using safe hash algorithms and using a salt for password hashing.. When I took a look at the source code of django-registration,I found that `sha1` is used for creating `activation_key`

```
activation_key = hashlib.sha1(salt+username).hexdigest()
```

`sha1` to my knowledge, is no longer a safe hash algorithm.
I was wondering if there was some way I could set the hash algorithm to be used .

what do you guys recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you re-examine what it's being used for here. When used to store an unsalted password, SHA-1 is weak. When used with a salt to generate a not-quite-random identifier, it is fairly safe.